# Ladder website for creating brackets and tournaments

Tags: starcraft-2, dota-2

There was a really sweet free website that allowed me to create a tournament with brackets of a few types.

I can't remember it now. Can anyone recommend a good bracket/ladder creation site?

Comment: Have you looked into [Challonge](http://challonge.com/)?

Comment: @Yves That looks great also! Thanks a bunch, you should post it up as an answer.

Comment: Try http://www.printyourbrackets.com/, but you have to do most of the work yourself.

Comment: Hi @drozzy, unfortunately I'm closing your question as off-topic. This is only barely tangentially related to gaming and not really related at all to solving a gaming *problem*. In addition, asking for website recommendations is problematic here and generally disallowed because people tend to post single sites as answers, which creates skewed voting patterns (people upvoting answers they *like* rather than answers of *good quality*). Feel free to check out the [FAQ] or join our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) if you have more questions about what is and isn't allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Challonge](http://challonge.com/) provides a very nice service (for free!) that lets you choose between several tournament types. The interface is pretty friendly and the service itself is great!

Comment: Challonge is good, z33k also worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few tournament websites for creating your own tournaments and amazing bracket systems. As Yves suggested, there is Challonge. As Decency mentioned, before I could, Z33k is another tournament websites that I use a lot. There is also playhem tournaments which you can offer money rewards, etc.